# Evaluating $ \int_0^{\infty } \exp\left(-g x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^2 z}{1-z}\right) x^k \sin(hx) \, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm attempting to evaluate the following integral, so far, with little success. Any help would be appreciated:

$$
\ \int_0^{\infty } \exp\left(-g x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^2 z}{1-z}\right) x^k \sin(hx) \, dx
$$

All paramaters are real.

Mx

Comment: Why did you write it in Mathematca notation rather than mathematics notation?

Comment: @GEdgar: Probably familiarity.

Comment: I would consider this as a family of integrals parametrised by $k$. Write $I_k$ for the corresponding integral. Integration by parts should give you a relation between different $I_k$ probably recursion-like. Maybe this helps.

Comment: One *evaluates* integrals, and *solves* equations.

Comment: @SimonMarkett Isn't $k$ real? OP says *all parameters are real*.

Comment: There is a $(1-z)^{-1-k}$ term that seems irrelevant. A typo?

Comment: @JoeL - Yes, typo.

Comment: @Ragib - Correct (it is irrelevant), it comes from the original expression I am trying to solve. I will remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining summand is the exponents one has that the integral is a Laplace transform $x\to g$ of the function 
$f(x,a,h)=e^{-a x^2} x^k \sin hx\;$.
For $k=0$, $a,g>0\;$ Mma gives
$$
L[f]=
-\frac{i \sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{(g-i h)^2}{4 a}} \left(\text{erfc}\left(\frac{g-i h}{2
   \sqrt{a}}\right)-e^{\frac{i g h}{a}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{g+i h}{2
   \sqrt{a}}\right)\right)}{4 \sqrt{a}}.
$$
Now note that for natural $k$ the result is equal to 
$(-1)^k\frac{\partial^k}{\partial g^k}L[f]$, so it seems where is no good formula for arbitrary $k$.